# How to enable the Laravel app working in a subdomain to handle the requests from another subdomain, without changing the URL in the browser?

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess, subdomain

I have my Laravel app working in the `admin` subdomain:

```
admin.mysite.com
```

I would like to enable my Laravel app to also handle the requests coming from another subdomain;  `client.mysite.com`, for example. I'm trying to utilize the [Apache Rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/) feature for this; thus, I've created the following `.htaccess` file in the main directory of the *"client"* subdomain:

```
# file: /client/public/.htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)/?(.*)$  https://admin.mysite.com/bu/$1/$2 [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

That works, but I definitely don't want the URL to be changed in the browser. To that end, I tried the [`[P]` flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p) to no success. Eventually, I removed the `https://` part to avoid redirects*:

```
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)/?(.*)$  admin.mysite.com/bu/$1/$2 [L,NC]
```

But then, I get the following error:

> *Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.*

How to fix the error and make it work? And, is this the right way to accomplish such a task at all? (does it work with POST and all? Is there any better solutions?)

---

* *<sup>If you start the `substitution` argument in the `RewriteRule` with `https://` it will cause a Redirection (it's just like an External Redirect using the `[R]` flag). This will cause the browser to make a new request, hence changing the URL showed in the address bar.</sup>*

*<sup>Also, please consider that my app is on a shared host, thus I might not have access to some low-level features.</sup>*

Comment: Are `admin.mysite.com` and `client.mysite.com` pointing to same site root directory on same host?

Comment: @anubhava Hi, thanks for the response; the `admin.mysite.com` points to `/admin/public` and the `client.mysite.com` points to `/client/public`; I've created both of them on a same host.

Comment: Just change the settings for the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` of those http hosts to point to the same physical folder on the server side file system. And you need to take care that the app only hands out relative references (no absolut URLs).

Comment: @arkascha Hi, I want the `client.mysite.com` subdomain to represent a specific class of routes (presented via: `admin.mysite.com/bu/$1/$2`); and not to have it as an identical alias.

Comment: Sure, then add the required rewriting rule for that by using a `RewriteCond` to limit its application to that "client" subdomain. But you need to rewrite to a path, not to a URL. That _is_ possible if both http hosts share the same `DOCUMENT_ROOT` as I suggested.

Comment: @arkascha Thanks for your responses; That sounds promising; could you please elaborate on your suggestion, possibly by an example. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` of your `client.mysite.com` to point to the same directory where the main Laravel app resides (in your case, set it to `/admin/public`). Then utilize the [subdomain routing](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#route-group-subdomain-routing) facility in Laravel; the subdomain may be specified by calling the [`domain()`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html#method_domain) method:

```
Route::domain('client.mysite.com')->group(function () {
    Route::get('{username}', function ($username) {
        //
    });
});
```